# Docker start container takes different time on different machines

Tags: docker, jenkins

We build docker images and then create some containers for running tests. On my local machine, **my_container** takes `30-35 to be ready`, but on Jenkins it takes `50-55 to be ready` and similarly on Jenkins build nodes (when i run manually) `takes 45-52 to be ready`.

Due to which test cases mostly fail on jenkins, while works well on local machines. Any idea if someone has faced similar issue?

Will change in Jenkins build compute resources help in fixing this issue?

Comment: Do you mean that Docker is faster in faster machines, or something else?

Comment: Is the main concern that the tests are failing? Can't they wait ~20s longer to start, or poll the containers availability before running?

Comment: @StephanPieterse Yes, we have a timeout of 60s. For example: make -C tests will start few containers and then run the execution over them. So, if wait is increasing more than 59s, test will fail :(

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Looks like container creation is faster in faster machines. As i have same docker version across all my machine (local and Jenkins nodes).

Comment: doesnt docker compose have a feature to control startup of your containers? So you can run your tests when docker determines that the dependencies of your my_container are ready

Comment: From the other comments, I would say your most immediate solutions could be either. 1) Increase Jenkins build compute resources 2) Increase timeouts 3) Check if the container is up yet in some loop in the Makefile before continuing with the tests.
It might be worth exploring if the application can be made to start up faster, but that is not always a quick solution.